# How to set ClockIdentifier dynamically in WinRT app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, timepicker

I have a TimePicker and would like to set its ClockIdentifier property dynamically based on the time format supported by the locale of that system. I tried getting the `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat`, but, it does not have any property specifying whether current culture set on the system supports 12 hour time format or 24 hours format.
Any ideas?

Comment: `DateTimeFormatInfo` includes the `ShortTimePattern` and `LongTimePattern` properties. It's entirely possible that one of those will use the 12 hour format and one will use the 24 hour format... which do you want to use?

Comment: I want it to be coming from the locale which is set on the machine. So, suppose if the user is from a region which supports 12 hours format, it would be set to 12 hours format and otherwise.

Comment: You've missed my point - a single region can support *both* formats, one for long and one for short. The two patterns in `DateTimeFormatInfo` can be very different. If you have one which is `HH:mm` and one which is `h:mm:ss.fff tt` what would you want to use?

Comment: In that case, I think I might have to revisit my requirement and see if it is valid. Thanks for the explanation Jon.